# string argument for array static method header help for java

Tags: java

I have placed string argument in the method header called methodASet. Is it possible to use this string argument in the body and returns the words in the argument as a set? If so how do I do this? Thanks.

```
public class MyMates {

private static Set<String> names;
private static String[] name1 = null;
private static String[] name2 = null;
private static String[] name3 = null;


public MyMates() {
    methodASet(); // (2) but I then get a error message "methodASet(java.lang.String) in myMates cannot applied to ()
    names = new TreeSet<String>();
}

public static void methodASet(String aTemp) {

    name1 = new String[]{"Amy", "Jose", "Jeremy", "Alice", "Patrick"};
    name2 = new String[]{"Alan", "Amy", "Jeremy", "Helen", "Alexi"};
    name3 = new String[]{"Adel", "Aaron", "Amy", "James", "Alice"};

   return aTemp; // (1) is it like this? 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would add a String like aTemp to an existing set:

```
 static Set<String> names = new TreeSet<String>();

 public static void addToNames(String aTemp) {
   names.add(aTemp);
 }
```

You can do this with an array of names too. I show the easy way:

```
 static Set<String> names = new TreeSet<String>();

 public static void addToNames(String[] manyNames) {
   for(String name:manyNames)
     names.add(name);
 }
```

The Set has to be created before you can add any value (otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException`). `names` is declared as a static field, so you can use it inside the method body and don't have to return it.

You could use the (second) method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // assuming names is declared and constructed like shown above
   String[] name1 = new String[]{"Amy", "Jose", "Jeremy", "Alice", "Patrick"};
   String[] name2 = new String[]{"Alan", "Amy", "Jeremy", "Helen", "Alexi"};
   String[] name3 = new String[]{"Adel", "Aaron", "Amy", "James", "Alice"};

   addToNames(name1);
   addToNames(name2);
   addToNames(name3);

   // Prove that the set has no duplicates and is ordered:
   for(String name: names)
     System.out.println(name);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks Andreas_D. I hope one day I could be a brilliant programmer like yourself guys.

Comment: Don't you think the **static** set is a bad idea ? More globally, wouldn't it be better not using static fields/method here ?

Comment: @Sylvain - I agree, but for this answer I tried to stay very close to the code fragments from the question above, just to make it as easy as possible for the OP to understand the answer.

Comment: Ok, but I already answer him on a similar question, and I think he begins with java (and probably with programming in general). So could we drive him to a better (but simple) design, in order to give him some best practices to start with ?

Answer (score 1):

Your method `methodASet()` takes a `String` as an argument, so when you call the method, you must pass a `String` to it. You are trying to call it without an argument.

```
public MyMates() {
    methodASet("something");
    // ...
}
```

Also, your `methodASet()` method is `void`, which means that it does not return a value. So you can't `return aTemp;` from the method. Either remove the `return` statement, or declare that the method returns a `String`:

```
public static String methodASet(String aTemp) {
    // ...

    return aTemp;
}
```

Comment: yea this is an example I use all time. At times I am not sure what type of method header to use. Thanks Jesper.